# Grafana graph share without requiring login

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to use a direct link to a graph in grafana to save the png image to disk.

This requires cookies with saved data so the user doesn't have to log in (if they've accessed it before), but does have to log in otherwise.

I can't use the auth.anonymous settings in the grafana.ini file, because it will make everything available, which is not good.

Any hints on how to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got the answer?